# My Search Bar is acting strangely

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out why my search button jumps to the second line. As far as I can tell, I only have it set to be one line (45px) thick and it is ignoring that. Help please?

http://www.bootply.com/EwP07rHc52

Forgot to add the script i'm using to actively change the button appearance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        // select element styling
        $('select.select').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            if( $('option:selected', this).val() != ''  ) title = $('option:selected',this).text();
            $(this)
                .css({'z-index':10,'opacity':0,'-khtml-appearance':'none'})
                .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
                .change(function(){
                    val = $('option:selected',this).val();
                    $(this).next().text(val);
                    })
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have whitespace in your code and your input element is set to display as `inline-block` and not floated properly. That's what's causing that extra space that doesn't show up in Dev Tools.

If you change `float: center` to `float: left` on that `.summonerSearch` element, it will be fine.

See it here: http://www.bootply.com/ZIsn1phtco

Comment: Interestingly enough, this moves the text input box down and leaves the left option box up one line

Comment: Actually, I don't see any differences except for the right button, of course. Maybe you're talking about the outline that shows up when the input box has focus?

Comment: Nope, when i run it from notepad++ in chrome browser, they're still of different lines with the option box being a line above the other 2

Comment: They you have something different than those two bootplies.

Comment: Oh no, I know what it's doing now. MY work around involved js code that would generate a span that is what i wanted it to be. Now that span won't overlay the invisible option box like i want it to.